# Why my manifest.json loading require new ssl handshake?

Tags: performance, manifest

When I test my site on GTMetrix, loading manifest.json require new ssl handshake. The site already in HTTPS, the manifest also in HTTPS. This is weird. I tried on Chrome but the result is the same. Testing other site, like smashingmagazine, manifest.json loaded normally. How to fix this?

Here's the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `crossorigin = "use-credentials"` attribute to your link element. For example:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="https://your-site.com/manifest.json" crossorigin = "use-credentials">
```

Although no impact is expected on the perceived speed of the website, it is always nice to reduce the SSL handshakes to one-half.

Reason: It has to do with the following cross-origin requirement that is noted in MDN website (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest):

> Note: If the manifest requires credentials to fetch - the crossorigin
>   attribute must be set to "use-credentials", even if the manifest file
>   is in the same origin as the current page.

Comment: Hi somuch72, I updated my answer with the solution. As it turns out it was not a Chrome bug.

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? I vaguely remember trying this at the time, I don't remember it's working or not (I think it's not working), but I think `use credentials` means you have to login first to view the page, if you're not logged in then you won't have this manifest.json. My site's visitors don't need to logged in to view the content, so I didn't check further to use this attribute. I removed manifest.json altogether, my site's theme is white so I don't need manifest.json styling and I can put favicon directly though it's not the best.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it myself and it worked for my website. I have checked that this single change made it work. My website does not implement user login at all. You can use GTMetrix for my website to verify it yourself (https://eurocodeapplied.com). As a side note, I have noticed that in smashingmagazine.com they don't use crossorigin = "use-credentials" but they serve manifest.json through HTTP 1.1 and the rest of the website through HTTP 2.0. It may be relevant, but I cannot check this.

Comment: I just checked, well congratulation, you solved this! I did check Smashing at that moment but I didn't realize they use different HTTP protocol! Anyway, if you want to speed up your loading, you can try using `server push`, its improvement is amazing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am glad that it was solved.